# Editable columns: editable_checkbox not working with Mobile Safari

Tags: laravel-backpack

Working with the Editable Columns add-on (https://backpackforlaravel.com/products/editable-columns) I noticed that the editable_checkbox doesn’t work on Mobile Safari. Tested on iOS 15.6.1.

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: On it! I’ve just added a bug report and will follow up shortly.

Comment: thanks, it looks as if neither save, change, or any of the known touch events is triggered.

Comment: Wanted to add that the editable_switch column also doesn't work.

Comment: Good news! We merged PR https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/editable-columns/pull/71 which fixes the issue.